# Best/Most Comprehensive API for Stocks/Financial Data

Tags: web-services, api, rest, soap, finance

What is the most recommended free/public API for accessing financial market stats and stock quotes (preferrably real-time quotes)? I'm not too picky about how it's exposed (SOAP, REST, some proprietary XML setup, etc.), as long as it's got some decent documentation.

I'm planning to build a simple web dashboard in PHP with some basic data (basically a quick-n-dirty homepage), but may want to grow it into a full blown web app eventually. Any thoughts?

As I find some, I'll post a list here (feel free to comment if you've used any of them before):

**Free**

- [opentick](http://www.opentick.com/) ([soprano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49485/soprano)) // link doesn't work

**Not Free**

- [XigniteRealTime](http://www.xignite.com/product/global-real-time-stock-quote-data/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yahoo's api provides a CSV dump:

Example: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=msft&f=price

I'm not sure if it is documented or not, but this code sample should showcase all of the features (namely the stat types [parameter f in the query string].  I'm sure you can find documentation (official or not) if you search for it.

http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html

**Edit**

I found some unofficial documentation:

http://ilmusaham.wordpress.com/tag/stock-yahoo-data/

Comment: This does not support exchanges outside US

Comment: It does, you just have to suffix them with a custom code. Like to get AB Inbev's quote you pull ABI.B

Comment: yahoo api no longer working `It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com.`

Answer (score 16):

I usually find that [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/financial/api) is a good place to go when looking for APIs.

Comment: That's a meta answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Markit On Demand provides a set of free financial APIs for playing around with. Looks like there is a stock quote API, a stock ticker/company search and a charting API available. Look at http://dev.markitondemand.com

Comment: The TOS say you cannot use it for anything other than test applications or if you're a prospective employee.

Comment: There are not many stocks availlable. I could not find any DAX enterprise.

Comment: Link is now dead

Answer (score 3):

Last I looked -- a couple of years ago -- there wasn't an easy option and the "solution" (which I did not agree with) was screen-scraping a number of websites. It may be easier now but I would still be surprised to see something, well, useful.

The problem here is that the data is immensely valuable (and very expensive), so while defining a method of retrieving it would be easy, getting the trading venues to part with their data would be next to impossible. Some of the MTFs (currently) provide their data for free but I'm not sure how you would get it without paying someone else, like Reuters, for it.

Comment: What does MTF stand for?

Comment: "Multilateral trading facility." http://www.investorwords.com/16604/multilateral_trading_facility_MTF.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the links and tips under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763310/yahoo-finance-api) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the brokerage firms like TDAmeritrade have APIs you can use to get streaming data from their servers:

http://www.tdameritrade.com/tradingtools/partnertools/api_dev.html