# Stock Symbols using python

Tags: python

I am looking for some stock symbol look-up API. I could able to query yahoo finance with a symbol & could able to retrieve the stock price & other details.

Is there any API for stock symbol searches

Any help would be great ..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Python's [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) or the [mechanise](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library to scrape the data from a website which publishes this data.  Mechanise would be a better choice if the website requires some interaction before you can get hold of the data (like logging in).

EDIT - for getting stock quote for BT from Yahoo's UK site:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import re
>>> data = urllib.urlopen('http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=BT&m=L&d=').read()
>>> re.search('<span id="yfs_l10_bt-a\.l".*?>([0-9.]+)', data).group(1)
'122.00'
```

The id in the regular expression was taken by viewing the source of the page and finding the id of the tag that surrounded the data required.

Comment: You may be better off using [BeautifulSoup][1] than regular expressions for screen-scraping a web-page.

    [1] http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: A similar question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763310/yahoo-finance-api

Comment: urllib vs. urllib2 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to parsing the HTML you could be downloading a clean pre-formatted .csv file. See the tutorial at http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm. Found it in the question awatts linked to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't really looked into it in detail, but that's a much better idea.  Python has a csv module which would likely help too.

Comment: the gummy-stuff.org link how shows a letter from yahoo asking them to stop distributing the data so this answer should probably be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Company Fundamentals API at http://www.mergent.com/servius